# How to fix Linux filename tab autocomplete that is appending a space instead of trailing slash on directories?

Tags: bash, command-line, filenames, autocomplete

For some strange reason my filename autocomplete is behaving differently than normal.  Given the following file structure `./foobar/file.txt`, if I want to delete `file.txt`, I type `rm foob<TAB><TAB>` and let the command line autocomplete the filename out to `rm foobar/file.txt`.

But right now, after hitting the first `<TAB>` my command gets autocompleted to `rm foobar` (with a space after `foobar`).  Is it possible that I accidentally changed it to this behavior?  How can I change it back?

Comment: Is `foobar` a symlink or otherwise not a normal directory?

Comment: @jw013 No, it is a regular directory, not a symlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this is usually caused by some misbehaving configuration in one of the files in `/etc/bash_completion.d`, which get installed and updated as you install various packages.  My recommendation would be to move all files out of that directory, start a fresh shell, and see if the behavior returns to normal.  If so, you can move files back into that directory one (or a group) at a time to see which ones cause the problem.  Once you narrow it down, report a bug in whichever package installed that file!

Comment: This worked.  Guess what the culprit was - Adobe Reader.  *facepalm*  Think I'll have much luck reporting that bug?  I at least have to try, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use `complete -p rm` to see the current completion of `rm`, see if the bash function really works as you wanted.

If you don't need the completion of `rm`, e.g parameters like `-i`, just put a line like this in your bash config,

`complete -r rm; complete -o default rm` (Remove current completion and set the default one)